# Single Notification to multiple objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to post single notification and have two different objects execute two different methods?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"locationAdded" object:nil];
```

**OBJECT ONE:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(reloadAnnotations:) 
                                             name:@"locationAdded" 
                                           object:nil];
```

**OBJECT TWO:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(reloadAnnotations:) 
                                             name:@"locationAdded" 
                                           object:nil];
```

.
.
.

---

Or as I suspect would I need to post two separate notifications with unique names (i.e.)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateTable" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateMapView" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notification gets delivered to each observer, which has been added before posting it.
So you need only a single notification. The selectors can be different.

Comment: and call [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"locationAdded" object:nil];

Answer (score 2):

No, that's fine, a single notification is delivered to as many observers as there are registered for it.