# NSNotificationCenter won't run selector method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter

Hi I have a weird problem,

In my **MainViewController** class I post a notification when ever a button gets pressed

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"step" object:nil];`

in the class it self i have a observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(step) name:@"step" object:nil];
```

which runs the "step" method

```
- (void)step {
    NSLog(@"works");
}
```

and in another class called **Slide1ViewController** I have a observer as well

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"works 2");

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(step) name:@"step" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and the dealloc method removes it

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"step" object:nil];
}
```

In the MainViewController the method gets called, but never in the Slide1ViewController.

The Slide1ViewController gets initialized like that:

```
Slide1ViewController*test = [[Slide1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Slide1ViewController" bundle:nil];
test.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*0, 0, 1024, 768);
[contentScrollView addSubview:test.view];
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Slide1ViewController is in memory when the notification is sent?

Comment: Have you implemented the `step` method in `Slide1ViewController`?

Comment: How you are initializing your Slide1ViewController object? I guess you are not using [Slide1ViewController alloc]initWithNibName: function. I think you are using just init function. Can you post the code where you are allocating "Slide1ViewController"?

Comment: i don't know what u mean by that it gets alloced and inited in the main view controller before posting the notification. I don't know maybe adding the Slide1ViewControllers view to the scrollview in MainViewController as subview is a problem?

Comment: nope i do exactly what u wrote:
´Slide1ViewController*test = [[Slide1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Slide1ViewController" bundle:nil];
    test.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*0, 0, 1024, 768);

   [contentScrollView addSubview:test.view]; ´

Comment: Off topic: If you aren't using ARC you did miss the `[super dealloc]` in your dealloc.

Comment: i do use ARC (releases are forbidden)

Comment: Can you check by putting a breakpoint to "NSLog(@"works 2");
" line or check in debugger console whether "works 2" is being displayed.

Comment: NSLog(@"works 2"); gets called

Comment: I think @dasdom is on the right track.  You create `test` as a local variable and as soon as the method finishes where it's created, ARC will deallocate it if nothing else is holding a reference to it.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672765/single-notification-to-multiple-objects

Comment: so what should i do ? setting it as @property of MainViewController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @Phillip Mills you were right i needed to declare it as @property of MainViewController now it works !!! Big Thanks this problem was driving me crazy.

Comment: First reaction is you "post" before "add"  :-)

Answer (score 0):

you have to register your both observer before posting notification, so you have to intialize your Slide1viewcontroller in memory before posting notification.